# MongoDB SSD vs more RAM

Tags: mongodb

Is it better to order VPS with SSD drive or more RAM? SSD is quite expensive so far and MongoDB requires a lot of disk space. My current database size is ~50 GB, so would performance be better on SSD with 1 GB RAM or HDD with 8 GB RAM?

Comment: It depends on your usage pattern. If you have lots of writes, but few reads then disk speed is more important than memory. That being said 1GB of RAM sounds very low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with estimating what you think the working set of memory used by MongoDB size will be - some details on how to approach that estimate can be found here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/diagnostics/

It's a function of the set of data that your application routinely accesses plus the amount of the indexes that need to be kept in memory. If you don't have enough memory to do that my experience has been that performance drops off of a cliff fairly quickly. I think SSDs are great for database performance all around but again my experience has been that you're better off making certain your working set remains in memory.

In my opinion 1GB for a production system is rather low - this needs to handle the OS, mongod and other daemons, the working set, plus anything else you need to do on the server. And keep in mind that if your database is growing your working set size is likely growing too, if for no other reason than indexes getting larger.